# Statistics based gambling

Tags: statistics, reference-request, book-recommendation, gambling

I don't know if my question meets the criterion of the community or not.
Maybe my question has been asked many times, but I haven't found 100% covered answers.
In a few words my question is :
Is it mathematically possible to make regular profit in gambling (sport betting, online casino games, etc. ) ?
In a bit detailed version it'll sound like this:
There are a lot off statistics of football, tennis, and other sports. What I want is to find a way to combine mathematical skills, programming skills, sport skills and of course personal luck (as it is sport) to make some math based strategies to try to beat the bookies. So is there any source(e.g. academic paper, book) which mathematically gives the way how to use that data, what to expect from various strategies and so on and so forth ?

Comment: [Edward O. Thorp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_O._Thorp)

Answer (score 2):

Your question is indeed off topic here, but I'll do a short answer anyway.

The only way to beat the bookies is to be a lot better than the average better in the long run at predicting who will win and by how much. Mathematical, statistical and computer tools can help some with that, but can only help. To make a living you'd need a lot of capital and be able to absorb short run losses in order to make a long run average gain. Roughly speaking, you bet on long shots. The fact that most people don't is how some online sports and fantasy sports betting websites make their profit.

You can't win at the casino games that are pure luck (roulette, slots). You can win at poker if you're enough better than the other players to take home money even after the house takes its share of the pot. You could once win, slowly, at blackjack, by "counting cards" but the casinos have made that much harder in various ways.